# xdebug/netbeans won't stop at any breakpoint other than in Joomla index.php

Tags: netbeans, joomla, xdebug

I'm a newbie with IDEs, I used Eclipse so far but more like an fancy text editor. I now switched to Netbeans and set it up for Joomla extension development, for which I followed the steps in various tutorials.
Everything works great except debugging. I set up xdebug and it works if I have breakpoints in the Joomla index.php file, but breakpoints in the php files of my component (for example in on e of the model functions) were just ignored.

My setup:
Joomla 2.5
Netbeans 7.4
XAMPP 3.1
xdebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both eclipse and netbeans, a prerequisite for debugging is that the project is built.

"Building" doesn't do anything real: php code is not compiled. But it allows the IDE to build a dependency tree, validate the code, allow code completion and follow execution flow from one class to the next.

To build, in eclipse either right click on the project or choose Project/Build from the menu. I have set Build automatically so the resources stay in sync while I work:

[image]

Comment: I googled but couldn't really find what I need to do. Do you mean with ANT? "Build Project" in Netbeans -> Run is grayed out

Comment: Are you using Build Automatically? That should be sufficient, try turning it off and hopefully it will un-gray. I edited the answer with a screenshot from eclipse/php.

Comment: I can't find that option in Netbeans

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/NetBeans_overview might give you what you need apparently netbeans fails to detect the web root sometimes, look up the chapter named "Creating a project and debugging"

Comment: I deleted in 'project properties' -> 'Run Configuration' all Configurations except <default> and changed there the 'Project URL' from http://localhost/joomla/ to http://localhost/joomla/administrator/ (Index File: index.php) since I want to debug in the backend. And I restarted Netbeans.

Comment: Now it stops at any breakpoint in all files, but I get Warnings for each breakpoint  
_(1) Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in C:\xampp... on line <line of bp>_ 
and   
_(2) Warning: main(): Property access is not allowed yet in C:\xampp... on line <line of bp>_
twice (1), then (2), then (1)&(2) again

Comment: Got rid of the warnings by switching in Joomla from Mysqli to Mysql

Comment: Nice that you got it going. But for the sake of completeness, can you check if netbeans is missing mysqli support? This is fairly strange... and will drive more people crazy!

Comment: Sorry, I was pretty busy and couldn't work on this side project. I don't know how to check that, I googled for it but couldn't find a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same problem, but solution is rather tricky. Actually netbeans stops on breakpoints but no all lines are eligible for breaking. When you put breakpoint wait a little, if beside green square there appears black arrow pointing down then it is OK, otherwise try some other line.